# How to avoid unwanted empty page

Tags: xsl-fo

The following FO code is created by an XSL transformation. The result shall be a long PDF containing multiple pages. The content of page 1 might spill over to the next page. There might be the need for deliberately adding another page (Page 2 of 2 in this example). When I run the sample through a FO interpreter (I tried Apache's FOP as well as Compart's DocBridgeMill), I get this PDF:

- "Page 1 of 1"
- empty page
- "Page 1 of 2"
- "Page 2 of 2"

I want to get rid of the empty page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master 
            margin-top="5mm" margin-left="10mm"
            page-width="210mm" page-height="50mm" master-name="FirstPage">
            <fo:region-body />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:simple-page-master 
            margin-top="10mm" margin-left="10mm"
            page-width="210mm" page-height="50mm" master-name="OtherPage">
            <fo:region-body />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master
            master-name="PageSequence">
            <fo:single-page-master-reference
                master-reference="FirstPage" />
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference
                master-reference="OtherPage" />
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master
            master-name="FollowingPages">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference
                master-reference="OtherPage" />
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence initial-page-number="1"
        master-reference="PageSequence">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                Page
                <fo:page-number />
                of
                <fo:page-number-citation
                    ref-id="5DAF3593E443DF58C1258934005BD76B" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block id="5DAF3593E443DF58C1258934005BD76B" />
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence initial-page-number="1"
        master-reference="PageSequence">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                Page
                <fo:page-number />
                of
                <fo:page-number-citation
                    ref-id="0C36B169CFBCD3DFC12589360067818E" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="FollowingPages">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                Page
                <fo:page-number />
                of
                <fo:page-number-citation
                    ref-id="0C36B169CFBCD3DFC12589360067818E" />
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block id="0C36B169CFBCD3DFC12589360067818E" />
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSL-FO is written with the assumption that odd-numbered pages are on the recto (left, for us) side of a two-page spread and that even-numbered pages are on the verso (back, or right) side.

The `initial-page-number="1"` on the second `fo:page-sequence` causes the formatter to emit the blank page after the first page sequence so that the second page sequence starts on a recto page as requested (however inadvertently). See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#initial-page-number

---

If you were using Antenna House Formatter (and added `xmlns:axf="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions"` to the XSL-FO), you could use the `axf:origin-id` extension to get the effect that you want. See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.origin-id

```
    <fo:page-sequence initial-page-number="1" id="seq1"
        master-reference="PageSequence">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                Page
                <fo:page-number />
                of
                <fo:page-number-citation-last
                    ref-id="seq1" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence id="seq2"
        master-reference="PageSequence">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                Page
                <fo:page-number axf:origin-id="seq2" />
                of
                <fo:page-number-citation axf:origin-id="seq2"
                    ref-id="seq-last" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="FollowingPages"
              id="seq-last">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                Page
                <fo:page-number axf:origin-id="seq2" />
                of
                <fo:page-number-citation-last axf:origin-id="seq2"
                    ref-id="seq-last" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
```

Comment: That was the hint I was needing. I can't remove `initial-page-number` because the individual documents in the PDF start with page 1. But adding `force-page-count="no-force"` resolved the problem.

Comment: I really should have thought of `force-page-count="no-force"`. Good that you found it despite me.